# Skip certain path on Spring SAML SSO

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

The web site contextPath is root, http://localhost:8080, use Spring security SAML implemented single sign on. Whatever the url enter under the localhost:8080 root path, it will direct to IDP provider for authentication which is correct so far.

What I want is under localhost:8080/unsecure directory, users can access without need to redirect to IDP for authentication. I don't know where to configure to tell SAML skip certain path.

Answer (score 0):

In your security-applicationContext.xml file you must have mapped urls something like this while configuring spring-security-saml:

```
<!-- Unsecured pages -->
<security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>

<!-- Security for the administration UI -->
<security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" use-expressions="false">
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/saml/web/metadata/login"/>
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>
```

Here we have allowed images, css, favicon etc to be available without login. So **add more URLs to the unsecured mapping list** if you want it to be available without authentication.